Why I get a message error opening a xlsm file if there isn't any macro supposed to be lauched at the opening of the file?
I just transformed a xls file into a xlsm one, adding a very simple sub.
The macro is not supposed to be lauched at the opening of the file, but just clicking a button.
THe button call the sub, that is included into a module
The problem is that opening the file it appears a message like:
"Impossible to find #RIF!#RIF!, that must be executed every time the file is opening. Continuation could cause errors". 
Any idea? It is the first time I see something like that... Could depend on the fact into the file there are some Pivot tables?
Should open the file without any message error

Does a message "like" the one you wrote appear? Or something starting with Cannot find #REF!#REF!, which has been assigned to run each time....? In such a case the error may not be related to VBA. It is a formula wrong reference... Try checking all names in Formulas - Name Manager. Correct the references or delete the ones containing #REF! in their Value.

you are right. Many thnaks for the advise. Problem fixed.
